# Javascript float sum not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tryng to sum two floating point numbers in this way:

```
total= parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next("div").find(".value").text()));
totale = total.toFixed(2);
console.log(total);
```

At first, total is 0 and the jQuery selector takes the second number that is "35,15". This results in total=35. Anyone could explain what am I doing wrong? Is the comma in number format the problem?

Comment: yes the comma is the problem. Is it supposed to be `35.15`? and if so why are you using a comma?

Comment: My format is with comma. How can i transform it with the dot? @Craicerjack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace(',','.')` to replace the comma with a decimal point and then parse the number.

```
total= parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next("div").find(".value").text().replace(',','.')));
totale = total.toFixed(2);
console.log(total);
```

Comment: That's working perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

replace comma with dot using `replace(/,/g, '.') :`

```
total= parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().next("div").find(".value").text()).replace(/,/g, '.'));
totale = total.toFixed(2);
console.log(totale);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `,`. It needs to be a `.`.

Comment: Is there any way to transform it with dot?

Comment: the ugly way, is to do a `.replace(",", ".")`

Comment: the real solution is to show a msg to the user saying that they should use `.` because if someone enters `11,234.56` value you app will do everything wrong. if someone enters `11,234` (not 234 decimals, but thousands) again it will do it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `parseFloat("35,15")` will be 35 because this is not starndard convention. If you want to parse this number you must replace the `,`into a `.`. Like this `parseFloat(total.replace(',', '.'))`